# Possible to sort rendered images based on class of parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some images that are wrapped within  containers like this:

```
<div id="swatchcontainer">
    <div class="swatchimgouter">
        <div class="swatchimginner">
            <img src="whatever1.jpg" alt="some text" title="some text too"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="swatchimgouter">
        <div class="swatchimginner swatchdisabled">
            <img src="whatever2.jpg" alt="some text" title="some text too"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="swatchimgouter">
        <div class="swatchimginner">
            <img src="whatever3.jpg" alt="some text" title="some text too"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    etc., etc.

</div>
```

It's not mission critical, but I got to thinking that it's probably possible to sort these images fairly easy using JQuery. I would like to place all images that are wrapped in the "swatchdisabled" class at the end.

There could be a couple of dozen of these images. They're all styled with `float:left` and so they display horizontally in rows. Even if there are a couple of dozen, there are only 2 rows. Each of these images is 30 pixels by 30 pixels.

It's just a UI consideration. Makes it a lot easier to keep track of which items are disabled and which are enabled by placing all disabled images at the end.

If it's fairly simple to do this, I'll also need to keep their inner div classes with them.

Comment: what's the container for all of this?

Comment: They're all within another <div>

Comment: Engineer, raised a very good point in the comments of his answer, regarding performance differences between document scoped and specific scoped selectors. Out of curiosity I added a benchmark test using jsPerf (I hope I set it up right), adding all the working answers provided here. See the results here: http://jsperf.com/document-scope-vs-specific-scope Note the results may vary between different browsers. Feel free to keep adding different variations of code to the test :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$('.swatchdisabled').each(function(){
     $(this).parent().parent().append( $(this).parent() );
});
```

this will move all `.swatchimgouter` divs,which have `.swatchdisabled` class on `.swatchimginner` div, to the end of their parent.

Demo is [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5TLpR/1/).

Comment: I'm amazed that JQuery/Js does things so simply... although it's not working in my code. Will this still work after the web page has been rendered? Your code is triggered when a dropdown selection is made. Do I have to do anything to cause these div's to be redrawn?

Comment: This does work! My class is actually called swatchDisabled and not swatchdisabled. Made that correction and it works great. Wow, the code is so simple. Thanks again.

Comment: It's updated - the way it should have been asked. Thanks again.

Comment: @Engineer: Not sure if this executes faster but it saves you the explicit iterations: `var elementsToMove = $("div.swatchimgouter div.swatchdisabled").parent();
$("#swatchcontainer").append(elementsToMove);` See here the alternate demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5TLpR/2/ I think it may end up traversing the DOM less compared to the `each()` but I'm not 100% certain on that.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Yeah, it might be, but it's a *micro* optimization. And also you used 3 hardcoded values(I have used just one), which is not good at all.

Comment: @Engineer: Those hard-coded values are specific selectors to ensure no element with a class of `.swatchdisabled` is included which is not a `div` and not contained within the container `div` with `id = "swatchcontainer"`. In my humble oppinion that is better as I don't end up accidentally indluding elements outside that container bearing that class or elements which are not divs. It is just a personal preference I have to be as specific as possible with my selectors :) +1 anyway on your answer as it works and included a demo

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Yes, you have own opinion. But are your aware that '`div.swatchimgouter div.swatchdisabled`' is slower,than '`.swatchdisabled`' ?! :)

Comment: @Engineer: I don't know about perfomance (you could be right) but would be interested in seeing a jsPerf on it (I might try to set one up tonight). Regarding scope of selection: See results of simple class selection http://jsfiddle.net/5TLpR/3/ vs scoped selection http://jsfiddle.net/5TLpR/4/. (I included container as well now to ensure scoped selection)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Now see [this case](http://jsfiddle.net/5TLpR/5/).I think, both of us can create 'cases', when my and/or your solution could failed and/or succeeded. The truth is,that my solution was succeeded for the OP. Cheers

Comment: @Engineer: It's all good, I merely wanted to point out that by not specifying exact scope you leave yourself open for unexpected results, by being specific about your selectors you minimise that risk dramatically. It's all good and all solutions work, I would not have +1'ed your answer otherwise :). Regarding the performance question you raised earlier, I created a jsPerf test not modifying any code. See the results here: http://jsperf.com/document-scope-vs-specific-scope

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I have slightly modified my code. Look [here](http://jsperf.com/document-scope-vs-specific-scope/2).But again your solution is faster:). Good job

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.swatchdisabled').each(function() {
     $(this).closest('.swatchimgouter').appendTo($('#parentdiv'));
});
```

or

```
$('.swatchdisabled').each(function() {
     $(this).parent().appendTo($('#parentdiv'));
});
```

where `#parentid` is the common parent of all your wrapping div

Comment: I've tried both of your examples too. They aren't working either, but your and Engineer's examples give me something to work with. Thank you very much for these examples!

Comment: Yours works too Calderan. my class is swatchDisabled and not swatchdisabled. I didn't think about that when I posted the question. Thank you again!

Comment: It was my error. I asked the question and typed the code by hand instead of copy/paste. You were right. My bad. Question is updated for accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

A version that does not rely on the container div that you mention in the comments, it will just work with the given divs in your question:

```
$(".swatchimgouter").last().after("<div id='wall'></div>")
$(".swatchdisabled").each(function(){
    $("#wall").after($(this).parent());
});
$("#wall").remove();
```

You could squeeze more juice out but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you zaf. I didn't think the outer div would be needed. Thought somebody would just show me how to move the img tags and not worry about the divs. Otherwise I would have included the outer div in my question. I do get the idea in your example. Thanks!